# Jquery remove dynamically added rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list where I add rows with Add button using Jquery. Now I also want to remove the dynamically added rows so I created a delete button dynamically along with the rows too but that delete button is not working.

```
<div id="quantityTable">
     <div class="row frmrw">  
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label class="col-md-6 control-label" for="name">Quantity:</label>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                       <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Quantity" name="quantity"  />
                </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <div data-role="button" id="addQty" class="btn btn-success">Add Quantity</div>                         
     </div>
```

the jquery that appends a similar row in the list along with a remove button

```
$("#addQty").click(function () {

                $("#quantityTable").append("<div class=\"row frmrw\"> "+  
                                    "<div class=\"form-group col-md-6\"> "+
                                    "<div class=\"col-md-6\">"+
                                    "<input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" "+
                                    "placeholder=\"Quantity\" name=\"quantity\"  /> </div></div> "+
                                    "<div class=\"form-group col-md-6\">"+
                                    "<div data-role=\"button\" id=\"rmvQty\" class=\"btn btn-success\"> "+
                                    "Remove Quantity</div> </div> </div>");
            }
            );
```

Now when I click on the remove button I need to remove that `particular` row

```
$("#rmvQty").on("click", function () {
                console.log("as");
            });
```

Firstly the jquery for remove is not working and secondly how do I remove the row that was clicked on.

EDIT : my solution

```
$("#quantityTable").on("click", function (e) {
                if(e.target.id == "rmvQty" ){
                     e.target.parentNode.parentNode.remove();
                }
            });
```

Comment: Part of your problem is that you are adding duplicate ID fields. I'm pretty sure that `$('DUPEID') will only grab the first ID it finds, since IDs are supposed to be unique.

Comment: yes  that makes sense. I will need to give a different Id. What I can do is keep a counter and append the count to the Id. but then for remove Jquery i will N remove button and obviously i cant have that many jquery script. I guess i'll need to bubble up to the parent and parse the ID and accordingly delete the element

Comment: You shouldn't need to reference them with the ID, however, if your scope is handled correctly. As long as the root of each new row is listening for clicks from `.btn`, then it can remove itself, and you never need to worry about which row is which.

Answer (score 0):

The element doesn't exist on page load, so you can't bind an event to it this way.

You should use:

```
$(document).on('click', '#rmvQty', function(){
    console.log("as");
});
```

Comment: I don't think this is a good approach, sure it "works", but you shouldn't need to have the document listening for clicks, it should be encapsulated only to the elements in question.

Comment: True, this was just meant to illustrate how it works